# Image Tooltip exported to HTML

Tags: export, html, tooltip

```
Graphics@Tooltip[Hyperlink[{Purple, Rectangle[{0, 0}]}, "http://www.wolfram.com"], 
Graphics[Disk[]]]
```

Is it possible to make image tooltip kept in the html?

[image]

Comment: Related question: [How to work around incorrect tooltips in plots exported to HTML](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1947/245)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer in general is **no**, and I've also wished there was a simple way to do it. The *only exception* I know of is when you export a notebook with a `ContoutPlot` or `ListContourPlot` to `HTML`, as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1947/245). The exported `GIF` image actually contains a reference to an `image map` which is a very old-fashioned way of providing tooltip information in images embedded into `HTML`. However, the coordinate ranges in the image map are often too buggy to be of any use whatsoever. It's as if someone forgot to finish this project 15 years ago and it's been in that state ever since.

If you export graphics to `SVG` individually, I think a viable option is to post-process the `SVG` file and add tooltips, e.g. implemented in Javascript. However, making this (or an expanded image map approach) part of the notebook's HTML export is more difficult.

Comment: How funny! I was looking at your linked question yesterday.  It seems to me that the coordinate ranges might be the bounding box of the element (and these often overlap).