# Exporting Tooltip data to HTML

Tags: export, html, interactive, tooltip

It would be very useful if one could export interactive Tooltip graphics to an HTML file like:

```
Export["Desktop/test.html",
  Graphics[{
    Pink, Tooltip[Disk[{1, 2}, 1], "This is a disk"],
    Cyan, Tooltip[Disk[{3, 1}, 1], "This is another disk"],
    Blue, Tooltip[Disk[{4, 3}, 1], "This is a third disk"]
  }], "HTML"]
```

I would like to put this HTML file on the web and have anyone access an interactive graphic file (actually, much more complex than what is shown above, it has extensive geographic data with extensive Tooltip data per county. 
I can do this with .CDF but doing that requires people to download the CDF Player and to download a very big and cumbersome file.  I would hope that XML or HTML5 support will be coming in later versions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Go to https://dev.wolframcloud.com/app/ and create a new notebook. Copy and paste the `Graphics` part of your code (not `Export`) into the notebook and evaluate it. Then click "deploy" and choose "published page", then choose "static web page" and click "generate URL". You will now have a URL that you can share, it will look like a CDF but it will be made in HTML5/JavaScript, so others won't have to download the CDF player. There are ways to deploy content from inside Mathematica, I'm just pointing you to dev.wolframcloud.com because it's easy to try things out there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not ask a question, but requests an enhancement to  _Mathematica_ as as such is not suited to this site.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question because the question it implies is an interesting one and as the comment by @C.E. shows there are possible solutions.

Comment: Related: [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30485/4597](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30485/4597)