# Tooltip has problem in Cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

In desktop `Mathematica`:

```
image = Thumbnail[ExampleData[#]] & /@ RandomSample[ExampleData["TestImage"], 3];
pos = CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ {Entity["City", {"Hefei", "Anhui", "China"}], Entity["City", {"Lasa", "Xizang", "China"}], Entity["City", {"Xiamen", "Fujian", "China"}]};
GeoGraphics[{Red, PointSize[.01], Tooltip @@@ Transpose[{Point /@ GeoPosition /@ pos, image}]}, GeoRange -> Entity["Country", "China"]]
```

[image]

```
CloudDeploy[%, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

> [CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/ec5ca71e-1c0f-487b-\
>   963c-7e226e8fb914"]](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/ec5ca71e-1c0f-487b-963c-7e226e8fb914)

Open the URL in browser it can't interactive:

[image]

```
Export["test.wl", %%]
```

Then in [develop.wolframcloud.com/app](https://develop.wolframcloud.com/app),import the `test.wl`:

[image]

You see,it also can't interactive...

**But `Tooltip` with text actually can work [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/622f2293-edab-4bf2-b9cc-31455deb88d5).**

How to fix it?

***Reference:[Exporting Tooltip data to HTML](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98374/exporting-tooltip-data-to-html)***

***PS:Even in local machine,it can not display image via `Tooltip`.***

```
Export["test.html", %]
```

Comment: My rule of thumb: never assume anything works in the cloud

Comment: There are a decent number of common structures that don't at present work in the cloud, including anything with a special `Appearance`, such as a palette button or an action menu (since it uses the palette background). Same with group openers in notebooks. Also many of the little icons on structures like `Databin` just aren't there, or weren't a month ago. They're probably all coming, but Mathematica is massive and the cloud has enough other kinks and bugs to make this not a priority.